# How do I load a fixture into a template with a different model in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

The intent of my code is to be able to load various fixtures into a template. For example:

The family template:

```
{{#each model as family}}
<p>{{family.name}} + "is" + {{family.age}} + "years old"</p>
{{/each}}
```

The brothers fixture: `[{ id:1, name:"Greg", age:40 }]`

The sisters  fixture: `[{ id:1, name:"Mary", age:35 }]`

So that when I call:

`#/brothers` I'd get `<p>Greg is 40 years old</p>`

vs

`#/sisters` I'd get `<p>Mary is 35 years old</p>`

I figure I'm having trouble with 1) the correct routing. 2) usage of {{each}}/{{with}}. 3) usage of fixtures/models.  You can find EVERYTHING at my [github repo](https://github.com/saberprivateer/SubstituteModelwithFixtureExample).  Thanks in advance for the help!

Application Template - application.hbs:

```
<br><br>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">

        <li class="active"><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/brothers">Brothers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/sisters">Sisters</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="container">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Family template (to go into {{outlet}} of application) - family.hbs:

```
<h1>Fixtures and Models</h1>
{{#each in model as family}}
    <p>{{family.name}} is here</p>
{{else}}
    <li>DIDN'T WORK</li>
{{/each}}
```

Family models and fixtures - family.js:

```
App.Family = DS.Model.extend({
    name    : DS.attr(),
    age     : DS.attr()

});


App.Brothers = DS.Model.extend({
name    : DS.attr(),
age     : DS.attr()

});

App.Sisters = DS.Model.extend({
name    : DS.attr(),
age     : DS.attr()
});

App.Brothers.FIXTURES = [
  {
    "id"    : 1,
    "name"  : "Greg",
    "age"   : 10
  },
  {
    "id"    : 2,
    "name"  : "Mike",
    "age"   : 23
  }
];

App.Sisters.FIXTURES =
[
  {
    "id"    :1,
    "name"  :"Mary",
    "age"   :15
  },
  {
    "id"    :2,
    "name"  :"Gina",
    "age"   :34
  }
];
```

My app.js file for all the routes:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('application');
   this.resource('home');
   this.resource('brothers');
   this.resource('sisters');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
redirect: function() {
this.transitionTo('application');
}
});

App.FamilyRouter = Ember.Route.extend({
});

App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.FamilyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.BrothersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
this.store.find('brothers');
},
renderTemplate: function() {
return this.render('family');
}

});

App.SistersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
return this.store.find('sisters');
}

});
```

Again, you can find all the codez here at my [github repo](https://github.com/saberprivateer/SubstituteModelwithFixtureExample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two fixes.

First, you're using wrong `#each` syntax. Change it to this:

```
<h1>Fixtures and Models</h1>
{{#each family in model}}
    <p>{{family.name}} is here</p>
{{else}}
    <li>DIDN'T WORK</li>
{{/each}}
```

Second, you're not returning brothers models. Change to:

```
App.BrothersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('brothers');
    },
    templateName: 'family'
});
```

Comment: Hey panta82, that totally worked! This has been incredibly frustrating for me.  The code may be simple but wrapping my head around the right ember syntax hasn't been.  Thanks a ton for clarifying how to make these calls work. :D